# Pandas: Do and/or operation on series of booleans

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series of booleans and was wondering what the best way is to apply "or" or "and" to the whole series. I am thinking something along the lines of a Haskell

```
fold
```

From my understanding, the pandas

```
.apply
```

will apply a function to each element in the series so doesn't seem to do what I need.

Thanks,
Anne

Comment: pls show an example of your series and what you want as output

Comment: Google ``numpy.any`` and ``numpy.all``.

Comment: You can use `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

To get `True` if the 1st AND ALL other elements of a series are `True`, we can use the [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) method, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.Series([False, False, False]).all()
# False
pd.Series([False, False, True]).all()
# False
pd.Series([True, True, True]).all()
# True
```

To get `True` if the 1st OR ANY other element of a series is `True`, we can use the [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) method, like this:

```py
pd.Series([False, False, False]).any()
# False
pd.Series([False, False, True]).any()
# True
pd.Series([True, True, True]).any()
# True
```

PS: be aware of the behavior for series which do not contain (only) boolean values:

```py
pd.Series([]).all()
# True
pd.Series([True, True, 1.0]).all()
# 1.0
pd.Series([True, True, 'foobar']).all()
# 'foobar'
pd.Series(['Non empty', 'strings are', 'truthy']).all()
# 'truthy'
```

and

```py
pd.Series([]).any()
# False
pd.Series([False, False, 0.0]).any()
# 0.0
pd.Series([False, False, '']).any()
# ''
pd.Series([False, '', '<-- the empty string is "falsy"']).any()
# '<-- the empty string is "falsy"'
```